# Regular expression to match closest tag above specific word (HLS media playlist)

Tags: regex, http-live-streaming, python-re

Given a HLS media playlist as follows:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:NO
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:7
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0

#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2022-09-12T10:03:22.621+02:00
#EXTINF:6.666666667,
seg1.ts
#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2022-09-12T10:03:29.637+02:00
#EXTINF:6.666666667,
seg2.ts
#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2022-09-12T10:03:36.583+02:00
#EXTINF:6.666666666,
seg3.ts
```

I want to create a regular expression to match the datetime following the `EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME` tag closest to a specified .ts file name. For example, I want to be able to retrieve the datetime `2022-09-12T10:03:29.637+02:00`, by specifying that the match should end with `seg2.ts`. It should work even if new tags are added in between the file name and the `EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME` tag in the future.

[This pattern](https://regexr.com/6uf85) (`EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:(.*)[\s\S]*?seg2.ts`) is my best effort so far, but I can't figure out how make the match start at the last possible `EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME` tag. The lazy quantifier did not help. The group that is currently captured is the datetime following the first `EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME`, i.e. `2022-09-12T10:03:22.621+02:00`.

I also looked at using negative lookahead, but I can't figure out how to combine that with matching a variable number of characters and whitespaces before the `seg2.ts`.

I'm sure this has been answered before in another context, but I just can't find the right search terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `re.search` here along with a regex tempered dot trick:

```py
#Python 2.7.17

import re

inp = """#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:NO
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:7
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0

#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2022-09-12T10:03:22.621+02:00
#EXTINF:6.666666667,
seg1.ts
#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2022-09-12T10:03:29.637+02:00
#EXTINF:6.666666667,
seg2.ts
#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2022-09-12T10:03:36.583+02:00
#EXTINF:6.666666666,
seg3.ts"""

match = re.search(r'#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:(\S+)(?:(?!EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME).)*\bseg2\.ts', inp, flags=re.S)
if match:
    print(match.group(1))  # 2022-09-12T10:03:29.637+02:00
```

Here is an explanation of the regex pattern:

- `#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:`
- `(\S+)` match and capture the timestamp
- `(?:(?!EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME).)*` match all content WITHOUT crossing the next section
- `\bseg2\.ts` match the filename
  if match:

Answer (score 1):

You might write the pattern not crossing lines that start with `seg` lines, and then match `seg2.ts`

```
^#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:(.*)(?:\n(?!seg\d+\.ts$).*)*\nseg2\.ts$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:` Match literally
- `(.*)` Capture **group 1**, match the rest of the line (note that this can also match an empty string)
- `(?:\n(?!seg\d+\.ts$).*)*` Match all lines that do not start with the seq pattern
- `\nseg2\.ts` Match a newline and `seq2.ts`
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BlcTF1/1)

```
import re

pattern = r"^#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:(.*)(?:\n(?!seg\d+\.ts$).*)*\nseg2\.ts$"

s = ("#EXTM3U\n"
            "#EXT-X-VERSION:3\n"
            "#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:NO\n"
            "#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:7\n"
            "#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0\n\n"
            "#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2022-09-12T10:03:22.621+02:00\n"
            "#EXTINF:6.666666667,\n"
            "seg1.ts\n"
            "#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2022-09-12T10:03:29.637+02:00\n"
            "#EXTINF:6.666666667,\n"
            "seg2.ts\n"
            "#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2022-09-12T10:03:36.583+02:00\n"
            "#EXTINF:6.666666666,\n"
            "seg3.ts")

m = re.search(pattern, s, re.M)
if m:
    print(m.group(1))
```

Output

```
2022-09-12T10:03:29.637+02:00
```

---

If you also do not want to cross matching the #EXT-X parts in between, you can add that as an alternative to the negative lookahead:

```
^#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:(.*)(?:\n(?!seg\d+\.ts\b|#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:).*)*\nseg2\.ts$
```